# Como puedo recorrer un directorio y mostrar carpetas y sub carpetas que tienen extensión

Tags: python

Actualmente tengo lo siguiente en python, la ruta es C/users/documents/workspace
pero la función solo me lista lo que está en la ruta con la terminación .parquet, necesito que tambien busque o recorra todas las carpetas y subcarpetas y me traiga los directorios que terminan en .parquet como lo hace actualmente.
Agradezco su ayuda.

```
def get_parquets():
list_parquets = []
listaJson = []
act_hdfs = True if get_activate_hdfs() == 'on' else False
if act_hdfs:
    hdfs_cli = HdfsCli(get_hdfs_cli())
    listaJson = hdfs_cli.list_files(get_workspace_hdfs())
else:
    if os.path.exists(get_workspace()):
        listaJson = os.listdir(get_workspace())
        print ('listaJson', listaJson)
for folder in listaJson:
    if folder.endswith('.parquet'):
        list_parquets.append(folder)
return list_parquets
```

Comment: Aqui un ejemplo [dirToJson](https://github.com/bryr0/DirToJson/blob/master/dirs.py)

Answer (score 0):

Espero que sea lo que necesitas:

walk retorna una generador, este es recorrido por comprensión, obteniendo únicamente el segundo valor de la tupla que retorna **walk** (dirpath, *dirnames*, filenames), siempre y cuando el largo de éste sea mayor que cero, es decir, que tenga nombres de directorios. Dado que podría existir cualquier combinación de anidaciones de los directorios, el resultado es una lista, que probablemente, tiene a su vez, más listas. Algo así:

> lista_mezclada = ["fotos",["música1", "música2"], "videos"]

Luego uso la función **chain** de itertools, para aplanar la lista, dejando cada elemento al mismo nivel, y la retorno, quedando de la siguiente manera:

> lista_aplanada = ["fotos","música1", "música2", "videos"]

```
from os import walk
from itertools import chain


def traerParquetDesde(ruta):
   lista_mezclada  = [el[1] for el in walk(ruta) if len(el[1]) > 0]
   return [ele for ele in chain(*lista_mezclada) if ele.endswith(".parquet")]


print(traerParquetDesde("C:/Users"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Ya probe la función y funciona, ahora tengo otro inconveniente, como tal necesito listar todos los parquets dentro de un  cosa que al llamar la función que colocaste funciona pero al dar clic al boton procesar, cuando capturo el parquet seleccionado como no viene con la ruta desde donde está mi función de procesar no puede hacer el render html para visualizar en la vista el parquet

mi funcion es la siguiente

```
@cargaBasedatos.route('/procesar', methods=['POST'])
```

def procesar():

```
nombre_parquet = request.form.getlist('sel_dataset[]')
act_hdfs = True if get_activate_hdfs()=='on' else False
spark = create_sc()
datos = []
nombres = []
for i in range(len(nombre_parquet)):

    if act_hdfs:
        ruta_parquet = get_hdfs_path() + get_workspace_hdfs + '/' + nombre_parquet[i]
    else:
        ruta_parquet = (get_workspace() + nombre_parquet[i])

    data = spark.read.parquet(ruta_parquet)
    data = data.limit(6).toPandas()
    datos.append(pd_to_html_responsive(data))

nombres.append(nombre_parquet)

close_sc(spark)
return json.dumps({'data': datos,'nombre_parquet': nombre_parquet})
```

Lo que finalmente necesito es que en la vista salgan los parquet pero sin todo el path desde donde vienes es decir mi select debe quedar solo con el nombre del parquet, pero al capturarlo en procesar debo tener ese path desde donde esta el parquet para que pueda procesarlo y pintarlo en la vista, como la función solo lista los nombres la función procesar recibe solo nombre y cuando procesar la ruta que construye es

C/documents/workspace/nombre.parquet  lo que está mal ya que falta el path desde donde está ese parquet

mi vista debe verse así

Debajo de la lista está el boton de procesar que envía el listado de parquets seleccionados, pero no los envía con la ruta desde donde vienen solo está enviando el nombre y la función procesar construye la ruta a buscar así solo con el nombre y no desde donde esta realmente el archivo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y la otra función con la que si funciona me los lista así 
así funciona y se construye bien la ruta en procesar porque al seleccionar los parquet va con todo el path pero se necesita tener en el select solo el nombre del parque y no todo el path pero a su vez mantener ese path para capturarlo en procesar